# How to pass multiple variables to for each loop via Collections In ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

i want the pass set variables to for each loop via collections. i am storing the query in the set variables and loop through these queries inside foreach by iteration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple array variables inside the For-Each, you need to use an index array in it. But the arrays length should be same.

Here is a demo for the above scenario:

I have created two array variables with queries named as  `query1` and `query2` respectively with below values.

**`query1` variable:**

```
["select ID ","select ID,City ","select * "]
```

**`query2` variable:**

```
["from cityA","from cityB","from target1"]
```

Create the index array using any one array length and pass to the For-Each using below expression.

```
@range(0,length(variables('query1')))
```

[image]

If the arrays length is 3, this expression will generate the index array like `[0,1,2]`.

Inside the loop, use lookup or script activity as per your requirement. Here I have used lookup. Build the query like below.

```
@concat(variables('query1')[item()],variables('query2')[item()])
```

[image]

Debug the pipeline and it will give the desired result and you can see the required query in the input of each lookup activity.

[image]